# How to get Pre-trained XLNET Sentence embeddings?

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, bert-language-model, johnsnowlabs-spark-nlp

I want to get XLNET Pre-trained Sentence Embeddings of any given sentence. Please provide a code snippet to get the embeddings

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the Hugging Face XLNet model [usage example](https://huggingface.co/xlnet-base-cased?text=My%20name%20is%20Thomas%20and%20my%20main#usage). For more detail of how to use transformers, please refer to the [Hugging Face official course](https://huggingface.co/course/).

```
from transformers import XLNetTokenizer, XLNetModel
import torch

tokenizer = XLNetTokenizer.from_pretrained("xlnet-base-cased")
model = XLNetModel.from_pretrained("xlnet-base-cased")

inputs = tokenizer("Hello, my dog is cute", return_tensors="pt")
outputs = model(**inputs)

last_hidden_states = outputs.last_hidden_state
```